# Black Screen after using navigator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here are the code segments from three files using Navigator Route .
The output is just a blank screen while routing to the next page.

**main.dart**

I've initilised the routing name in here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './homepage.dart';
import './itemdetails.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(............
    .................................
    .................................
        routes: {
        '/': (ctx) => HomePage(),
        DetailsScreen.routname: (ctx) => DetailsScreen()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**homepage.dart**

```
..........................
..............................
..............................
class CardDesign extends StatelessWidget {
  void itemDetails(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      DetailsScreen.routname,
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => itemDetails(context),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
        elevation: 3,..........
.....................
.................
```

**itemdetails.dart**

the final page showing blank screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routname = '/DetailsScreen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("hlooo"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which page HomePage or DetailsScreen show blank screen?

Comment: DetailScreen is showing a black screen.

Comment: If you can please share your project in Github and after that, I will fix your issue

Comment: In MaterialApp  assign  theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white
      ),

Comment: https://github.com/glootieC311/xarothi

Comment: I've shared the lib and assets folder in github..please help me out

Comment: @jivanpatel I tried , but it is just a black screen

Comment: @muqaddirX I got the issue...  you are using FloatingActionButton in CardDesign class just replace that with some other widget.

Comment: because FloatingActionButton use 'herotag' and that need to be different for all floating button in the same context.  in your code, it was the same for all because you not assigned anything and by default, it was null.